# React - Unexpected behavior possibly caused by passing functions as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a list of thumbnail image components which when clicked will update the state of the parent. Eventually, I do get the desired behavior, but it takes several clicks and the effect is usually one-click behind the input. I'm speculating that this has something to do with how the functions are being passed as props, but am completely at a loss for what's going on.

EDIT: I think the issue is that the page renders before the setState changes the image state, which is why each click executes with the image that was passed via the previous click. I either need to fin a way to wait until the state updates to render, or do something in ComponentDidUpdate to rerender the page (which seems hackish but still a possibility).

This is the code I have so far:

```
var ImageSelector = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        imgState:  "<%= image_path('image1.jpg') %>"
    }
},

_changePicState: function(thumbnail){
    var newImage = thumbnail.props.imageLink
    this.setState({imgState: newImage})
},

_getThumbnails: function(){
    console.log('_getThumbnails')
    const thumbnailList = [
    {id: 1, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image1.jpg') %>"},
    {id: 2, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image3.jpg') %>"},
    {id: 3, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image7.jpg') %>"},
    ]

    return thumbnailList.map((e) => {
        return (
            <ImageThumbnail key={e.id} imageLink={e.imageLink} propFunc={this._changePicState}/>
            )
    });
},

render: function() {
const thumbnails = this._getThumbnails()

return (
    <div>
    {thumbnails}
    <MyCanvasComponent ref="canvasComp" imageLink={this.state.imgState}/>
    </div>

)
}

});

var ImageThumbnail = React.createClass({
_runPropFunc: function(){
    this.props.propFunc(this)
},

render: function(){
    return (
        <img key={this.props.id} src={this.props.imageLink} className="thumbnail" onClick={this._runPropFunc} />
        )
}
})
```

EDIT: Including the myCanvasComponent code below.

```
var MyCanvasComponent = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        currentImage: this.props.imageLink
    }
},
componentDidUpdate: function(){
    this._draw()
},

_draw: function(){
    var draw = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(objectImg, 100, 100);
    }
    var can = this.refs.canvas;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

    var objectImg = new Image();
    var imgPath = this.state.currentImage;
    objectImg.src = imgPath
    console.log('drawing ' + imgPath)

    objectImg.onload = function(){
        draw();
    }
},


componentWillReceiveProps: function(){
    this.setState({currentImage: this.props.imageLink});
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    console.log('canvas rendered')
    this._draw()

},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        <canvas ref='canvas' width={867} height={600}/>
        </div>
    );
}
})
```

Comment: Could you post your `MyCanvasComponent` code please ? Because I wrote an implementation base on your question with your code and it works as expected.

Comment: No problem. I just posted it below the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the issue with the bellow code ?

Comment: The issue was that React was rendering the new myCanvasComponent before updating the state with the new image for some reason. So the image of the thumbnail that was click wouldn't get drawn until the next click. It has something to do with how React batches things based on what it expects to happen. I figured out a workaround though in the comments below (not the original post) and just included the drawing into the image selector tab which guarantees that it will draw after the state changes.

Comment: Yes I understood that but I wanted to see the original code (not the modified one in your answer) because I think you could have use the second parameter of `setState` which is a callback triggered when the state is actually updated.

Comment: I tried doing that as well with a callback function of console.log(this.state.imageLink) and that ended up logging the previous state. I never really figured out why that was happening though. Perhaps it was another type of caching issue?

Comment: Ok, the problem lies in your `MyCanvasComponent`, you just avoided to use the `nextProps` params in the `componentWillReceiveProps` callback. By the way, making `MyCanvasComponent` statefull is not relevant here. See my answer below with a working snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your `MyCanvasComponent`. You're setting the new state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method by using `this.props` but `this.props` references the old props, [the new props are passed as a parameter to the `componentWillReceiveProps` function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops)

By the way, you don't need to hold the current image in the `MyCanvasComponent` since this state is already managed by the `ImageSelector` component, passing down the current image from `ImageSelector` to `MyCanvasComponent` is sufficient in this case :

```js
var ImageSelector = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            imgState:  "https://rawgit.com/gorangajic/react-icons/master/react-icons.svg"
        }
    },

    _changePicState: function(imageLink){
        this.setState({imgState: imageLink})
    },

    _getThumbnails: function(){
        const thumbnailList = [
        {id: 1, imageLink: "https://rawgit.com/gorangajic/react-icons/master/react-icons.svg"},
        {id: 2, imageLink: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media-p.slid.es/uploads/jhabdas/images/969312/react-logo-1000-transparent.png"},
        {id: 3, imageLink: "http://felknar.com/images/icon-react-7b609cd3.svg"},
        ]

        return thumbnailList.map((e) => {
            return (
                <ImageThumbnail key={e.id} imageLink={e.imageLink} onClick={this._changePicState}/>
                )
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        const thumbnails = this._getThumbnails()

        return (
            <div>
            {thumbnails}
            <MyCanvasComponent imageLink={this.state.imgState}/>
            </div>

        )
    }

});

var ImageThumbnail = React.createClass({

    _runPropFunc: function(){
        this.props.onClick(this.props.imageLink)

    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <img key={this.props.id} width={50} height={50} src={this.props.imageLink} className="thumbnail" onClick={this._runPropFunc} />
            )
    }
})


var MyCanvasComponent = React.createClass({

    _draw: function(){
        var draw = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(objectImg, 100, 100);
        }
        var can = this.refs.canvas;
        var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

        var objectImg = new Image();
        var imgPath = this.props.imageLink;
        objectImg.src = imgPath

        objectImg.onload = function(){
            draw();
        }
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function(){
        this._draw()
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        this._draw()
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <canvas ref='canvas' width={867} height={600}/>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<ImageSelector/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes tons of sense! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't hesitate to mark this answer as accepted if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would drop the habit of prefixing your function names with underscores. It serves no purpose: it doesn't actually make them private functions. It's code mess, basically. That's probably a bit subjective, but I thought I'd offer that up anyway. :)

Secondly, in `ImageThumbnail`, I wouldn't pass `this` back to the parent, when all you really need is the `imageLink`. So just pass that.

Try the code below. I also renamed the prop to `onClick` so it's clearer what's going on. When making your own components that have event handlers, try to stick to conventional names (`onClick`, `onChange`, `onDeleteThumbnail`). It'll make your life easier!

[image]

Side note: If you have time, try to get on board with the [ES2015 class way of doing things](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

```
var ImageSelector = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      imgState: "<%= image_path('image1.jpg') %>"
    }
  },

  changePicState: function (imageLink) {
    this.setState({ imgState: imageLink });
  },

  getThumbnails: function () {
    console.log('getThumbnails');
    const thumbnailList = [
      { id: 1, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image1.jpg') %>" },
      { id: 2, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image3.jpg') %>" },
      { id: 3, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image7.jpg') %>" },
    ];

    return thumbnailList.map((e) => {
      return (
        <ImageThumbnail key={e.id} imageLink={e.imageLink}
                        onClick={this.changePicState} />
      )
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.getThumbnails()}</div>
        <div>{this.state.imgState}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var ImageThumbnail = React.createClass({
  runPropFunc: function () {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.imageLink);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <img key={this.props.id} src={this.props.imageLink} className="thumbnail"
           onClick={this.runPropFunc} />
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! As far as the underscores, I just started working through the CodeSchool tutorial and it was something they used to differentiate between the lifecycle functions and ones I made, so thanks for pointing out that that's not preferable.

The issue actually had to do with React batching the state change until after rendering the other canvas component (maybe because it didn't expect the state change to affect it?) For some reason, React is changing the state before rendering in your code, but was rendering and then changing the state in mine. I'll post hackish fix below.

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't get rid of the underscores, but it's on the to-do list.  I feel like this component might be getting a bit bloated, but it ensures that the new canvas element gets drawn after the state change.  Previously, the state change would be queued and the new component would be rendered (along with the draw function which used to be in the MyCanvasComponent) and the state would change after rendering, so everything lagged behind by one click.

Thank you once again for your help!

```
var ImageSelector = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        imgState:  "<%= image_path('image1.jpg') %>"
    }
},

_draw: function(){
    var draw = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(objectImg, 100, 100);
    }
    var can = this.refs.canvas;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

    var objectImg = new Image();
    var imgPath = this.state.imgState;
    objectImg.src = imgPath

    objectImg.onload = function(){
        draw();
    }
},

componentDidUpdate: function(){
    this._draw()
},
componentDidMount: function(){
    this._draw()
},

_changePicState: function(imageLink){
    this.setState({imgState: imageLink})
},

_getThumbnails: function(){
    const thumbnailList = [
    {id: 1, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image1.jpg') %>"},
    {id: 2, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image3.jpg') %>"},
    {id: 3, imageLink: "<%= image_path('image7.jpg') %>"},
    ]

    return thumbnailList.map((e) => {
        return (
            <ImageThumbnail key={e.id} imageLink={e.imageLink} onClick={this._changePicState}/>
            )
    });
},

render: function() {
const thumbnails = this._getThumbnails()

return (
    <div>
    {thumbnails}
    <canvas ref='canvas' width={867} height={600}/>
    </div>

)
}

});

var ImageThumbnail = React.createClass({

_runPropFunc: function(){
    this.props.onClick(this.props.imageLink)

},

render: function(){
    return (
        <img key={this.props.id} src={this.props.imageLink} className="thumbnail" onClick={this._runPropFunc} />
        )
}
})
```